# It's possible to call functions in another schema from within plv8 functions?

Tags: postgresql, plv8

I'm trying to use plv8 to write postgres functions. Now I would like to use the pgcrypt library in a way like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION v01.myfunction(arg json) 
RETURNS json AS
$BODY$
  var res;
  res = obj.crypt(arg.password, res);
  plv8.elog(NOTICE, res);
  ...

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plv8;
```

Where crypt comes with the pgcrypt library and is find in another schema. But if running I get the error:

```
ERROR:  ReferenceError: obj is not defined
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it:

```
var pp = plv8.execute("SELECT obj.crypt($1,$2)",[arg.password, cpw]);
```

easy :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to call other PLV8 functions in other schemas, yes.

You're not calling the function right though. Use

```
var myFunction = plv8.find_function("schemaName.functionName")

var result = myFunction();
```

AFAIK you can only call other PLV8 functions this way, not say PLPGSQL.

You can use `plv8.execute("select someFunctionInAnotherLanguage()")`

Comment: thanks, I tried this as well but got an error as well. Obviously because pgcrypt delivers no plv8 functions. So in my case it doesn't help.

Comment: So I should ask: It's possible to call plpgsql functions from within plv8 functions?