# Access PostGIS Functions from plv8

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plv8

I am trying to write a plv8 function that returns an integer representing a UTM zone value.  The function utilizes PostGIS functions.  Here is the (not-functioning) idea:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION utm_z(geometry)
  RETURNS integer AS
  $$
    var geom_geog = st_transform($1, 4326);
    var utm_zone = Math.floor((st_x(geom_geog)+180)/6)+1;
    return utm_zone;
  $$ LANGUAGE plv8;
```

When invoking that function I get

`ERROR:  ReferenceError: st_transform is not defined`

How am I able to access those PostGIS functions from inside plv8?

EDIT:
PostGIS is installed and functioning in this DB.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of the function.  Surely there must be a better way to do this in plv8...?

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION utm_z(geometry)
  RETURNS integer AS
  $$
    var geom_geog_wkt =
        plv8.execute("SELECT st_transform($1::geometry, 4326);", $1)[0].st_transform;
    var utm_zone =
        Math.floor(
            plv8.execute(
            "SELECT (st_x($1::geometry)+180)/6+1 AS \"utm_z\"", geom_geog_wkt
            )[0].utm_z
        );
    return utm_zone;
  $$ LANGUAGE plv8;`

Running `plv8.execute()` returns an array of objects.  In the function above, I grab the 0th array object, and then access that object's value using the key, which is the first function name invoked inside the statement.

Answer (score 0):

First you need install Postgis to postgres

http://postgis.net/install/

Then add the postgis extension to your db

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I've definitely got PostGIS installed in this db.  Updated question with screenshot.

Comment: Looks like is a problem with plv8. Did you try create the same function using `LANGUAGE plpgsql` to test everything is ok?

Comment: Yes, I am actually trying to convert the function from an existing plpgsql one, into this new plv8 one.  plpgsql function works fine, but I'm not clear on how to access PostGIS functions from inside a plv8 block.

Comment: I tought was the extension problem. But I will leave my answer here in case other think the same. I also found this one, maybe help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627205/its-possible-to-call-functions-in-another-schema-from-within-plv8-functions?rq=1